# grep to file to exclude content

Tags: grep

i have this command:

```
grep -Pvi ".(\.var|\.foo|\.varfoo)$" myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

note: .var, .foo and .varfoo (and many others) are lines that are in myfile.txt.

myfile.txt:

```
.var
.foo
.varfoo
.xxx.var
.yyy.foo
.zzz.varfoo
```

The command works well and does what it has to do (eliminate any line that ends with .var, .foo, .varfoo, but keeping these 3). After executing the command:

newfile.txt

```
.var
.foo
.varfoo
```

Now, i need to put .var, .foo, .varfoo, in a "greplist.txt", to avoid putting them inside the command, so that "grep" reads it:

greplist.txt

```
.var
.foo
.varfoo
```

how do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two challenges here:

- `-P` only supports a single pattern
- each line in your file must be a full pattern, not just the text itself

So if you set `greplist.txt` to

```
.\.var$
.\.foo$
.\.varfoo$
```

and just run

```
grep -vi -f greplist.txt myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

you should get what you are looking for.

Comment: a question related. And if I wanted to do the opposite (keep .xxx.var, .yyy.foo, .zzz.varfoo in newfile.txt and delete .var .foo .varfoo). What should I put in the "greplist.txt" list (maybe ^\.var $   ...etc) ?? Thank you

Comment: @user4839775 Omit the `-v`. See `man grep` for what this does.